# Not able to post photos to facebook contacts

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook, ios5

In my iphone app i want to post photos to selected facebook contacts. I'm getting that photos from phone library.

I'm using this code:

```
fbString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",appdelegate.titleString,appdelegate.descriptionString];

NSArray *permissions =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_actions",@"publish_stream",@"manage_friendlists", nil];


    NSData* imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.img, 90);
    NSLog(@"imageData  %@",imageData);

    NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:fbString, @"message",imageData,@"source",nil];

NSLog(@"fbid count  %d",fbidarray.count);


[[FBSession activeSession] reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions:permissions
                                             defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                           completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error)
 {
     if (!error) {


         for(int j=0;j<fbidarray.count;j++)
         {


              [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/photos",[fbidarray objectAtIndex:j]] parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error1)
              {

                  NSLog(@"errors in the view %@",error1);


                  if(!error1 )
                  {

                      UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success"
                        message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" Sucessfully posted "]
                        delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                      [alertView show];

                  }
              }];
         }
 }   
 }];
```

Comment: I doubt on for loop, It is fast and it doesn't wait so dont do `startWithGraphPath:` in loop. Send another request when one has finished.

Comment: `NSData* imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.img, 90);` is also wrong **compressionQuality** is b/w 0 to 1.

Comment: I have tried this earlier and the problem is with "key", BTW Do you have the image URl?

Comment: no that image is getting from phone library

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
NSMutableDictionary *postTest = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [postTest setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat@"Your message"] forKey:@"message"];
    [postTest setObject:@"" forKey:@"picture"];
    [postTest setObject:@"" forKey:@"name"];
    [postTest setObject:@"APPID" forKey:@"app_id"];
    NSString *userFBID =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[allInfoDict objectForKey:@"Friends facebook ID "]];

    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/feed?access_token=%@",userFBID,[appDelegate.mysession accessToken]]
                                 parameters:postTest
                                 HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              NSDictionary * result,
                                              NSError *error) {
                              if (error) {
                                  [self hideHUD];
                                  NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

                              } else {
                                  // Success

                              }
                          }];

    [postTest release];
```